# SQL Select rows in two tables with variability

Tags: sql

I have a problem in SQL that I didn't find a solution. (Sorry for the table format, it's my first question and I didn't get how to do it right yet...) I have two tables :

Tab1

```
ID | Time | Time20Min  
---|------ |---------------   
1  | 2:20   |  2:40    
2  |  5:13   |  5:33  
3  |  1:34    | 1:54
```

Tab2

```
ID   |  DateTime  
--- |----  
1   |   2:20  
1   |   2:32  
1   |   2:39  
1   |   2:45  
2   |   5:17  
2   |   5:23  
2   |   5:33  
2   |   5:42
```

I want to keep for each ID only lines where Tab2.DateTime is between Tab1.Time and Tab1.Time20Min and have :

Tab3

```
ID   |  DateTime  
--- |----  
1   |   2:20  
1   |   2:32  
1   |   2:39   
2   |   5:17  
2   |   5:23  
2   |   5:33
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you :-)

Comment: Simply join the tables. Have t2 column between t1 columns as join condition.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, simply highlight the relevant lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{   }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`

```
select t2.*        -- the t2 limits the results to this table only
from Tab1 t1       -- Tab1 is now aliased as t1
inner join Tab2 t2 -- JOIN to Tab2 and alias as t2
 on t2.DateTime between t1.Time and T1.Time20Min -- here is the JOIN condition
```

Comment: "Answers to questions tagged with `SQL` should use ISO/IEC standard SQL" - to make your SQL compliant with the required standard, surround the identifier `Time` with double quotes i.e. change `t1.Time` to `T1."Time"`.

Comment: That was it
Thank you ! :-)